# Can I leave it plugged in for charge all the time? -Samsung Galaxy 3 I5801

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-apollo, battery

In short my question is -
**What is the battery level at which it starts charging again Samsung Galaxy 3 I5801 device when kept plugged in for charge all the time?**

If you want to know background and why I ask this, read whole question below.

This question is based on below answer 
[Do I have to charge my phone before I use it the first time?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/do-i-have-to-charge-my-phone-before-i-use-it-the-first-time)

> Can I leave it plugged in all the
>   time? Yes, and no. This is very
>   dependent on whom makes your device.
>   For example, my Lenovo laptop will not
>   apply a charge to the battery unless
>   it is under 97%. When it does charge
>   the battery it charges directly to
>   100%, then stops until the battery
>   sags below 97%. Many laptops did not
>   do this, on most just applying charge
>   if it is not 100%. This would put the
>   battery through thousands of charge
>   cycles in a week when you are not
>   using the battery. This ages a battery
>   quickly.
>
> If your phone maker took the time and
>   paid the extra cash then your phone
>   will stop charging once it reaches
>   full charge and just power the system
>   from the wall outlet. It is
>   significantly more likely that your
>   phone is charging your battery on a
>   short cycle and aging it thoroughly.

The answerer mentions that it depends on manufacturer. What's the answer for Android phone? Or if it depends on the Manufacturer what is the battery level at which it starts charging again Samsung Galaxy 3 I5801 device?

So this question is specific to the device - Samsung Galaxy 3 I5801.

Comment: As you can tell from what you quoted, it will depend on the manufacturer.

Comment: @Cry, my mistake. I've now clarified the question. In short, what is the battery level at which it starts charging again Samsung Galaxy 3 I5801 device?

Comment: See also Does constant charging harm my cellphone? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-cellphone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about your specific device/battery but [here is a rather detailed article on the battery in android phones](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/12/14/your-battery-gauge-is-lying-to-you-everything-you-need-to-know-about-bump-charging-and-inconsistent-battery-drain/) and the app used in the article to log battery information is called [CurrentWidget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/currentwidget/com.manor.currentwidget)

If the article is representative of most smart phones, which I suspect it is, to maximize your battery life your phone does an initial charge to 100% and then maintains the battery at about 93%.

My takeaway is that it is good to leave your phone plugged in and charging when you can but it is not good to frequently plug and unplug your phone.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is safe to say that any modern equipment today will stop charging when the battery reaches full charge. And if it stays on the charger, the device will be powered on by the charger and the battery will not run down. So leaving the equipment plugged all the time should be the equivalent of leaving the device turned off with a full battery inside. As it is said in the reply mentioned in the comments, the best thing to do when storing a battery for a long time is to leave it to 40% charge, but 100% will not harm the device unless you leave it for a **very** long time.

As an example, since batteries are limited in their amount of charge cycles, it is better to leave it on the charger if don't use the device for a couple of days than to disconnect and reconnect it every day and use some of the cycles.

Personally, I have a 1st gen iPod Touch that is docked most of the time, even for up to a complete month, and the battery is almost at full capacity even after 3 years.

Comment: The vast majority of devices I have used do not switch away from battery power when plugged in.  It's certainly not safe to say even if my experience is not the norm.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? When the devices you have used are connected, they will charge until they reach full charge, right? but what are they going to do next?