# Do Samsung batteries actually charge to 100% capacity?

Tags: battery-life

My understanding on Li-on batteries is that they don't like to be charged to 100% capacity and that it can prematurely degrade the battery. Something to do with voltage increasing and heat at the last 10% charging capacity? Do Samsung allow their batteries to be charged to an actual 100% capacity or do they actually only charge to 80% but appear as 100% to the user/consumer?

Comment: You should check out [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/5839/270645).

Answer (score 0):

First, a battery is not like a watter bottle with a clear, definite capacity. It's more like a balloon that you can charge more than it's designed for, but if you overcharge it, it gets damaged. There's a threshold that the battery manufacturer thinks "safe to charge to", and that's what you're presented with.

Comment: Why do people still recommend charging Li-on batteries in phones/devices to 80% then?

Comment: @Kol12 I never heard that. Usually I just leave my phone plugged when I'm at home or office. Li-ion batteries really don't need that much care.

Comment: Take a read of this: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries