# Is it OK to leave my Samsung Galaxy Ace charging all the time?

Tags: battery, charging, samsung-galaxy-ace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does constant charging harm my cellphone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-cellphone)

Hello!
I have the Samsung Galaxy Ace but the battery life is a bit of a problem for me. Can I leave it plugged in ie. charging all the time and just take it out when I need to? Or will I damage it?
Many thanks
Best
RD
x