# Phone connected to charger full time - never sleepmode - any danger?

Tags: charging, overheating

Yeah, might sound strange, but I managed do install Debian Linux on my Android phone. Because the phone needs very little power, it is, for me, the perfect server.

I plan to disable sleepmode and to leave the charger connected to the phone at all times.

Is there any danger in overheating, fire and so on?

Comment: Doesn't go into the fire/heat danger but this previous question covers what happens with the charging of your battery when you leave it plugged in constantly http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-cellphone

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the phone, my biggest worry would be screen burn. I have a Samsung Galaxy S Vibrant and I have screen burn at the top of my screen from the time and the notification bar.  A screen like a Super AMOLED is actually a lot easier to get screen burn then I thought it would be. It is actually pretty annoying now, I have to limit the background images I use, otherwise the burn is really noticeable.

Comment: In that case, Debian has screensavers, it's just a matter of turning one on. :)