# Battery Trickle Charging, good or bad?

Tags: battery

What are the side effects of using apps that trickle charge battery. App like "Battery Doctor". It charges around 30-50 (varies with device) mins after battery is fully charged, which results in a bit longer battery backup as I found out. But is that harmful for battery health? Like damaging the battery? Or should I charge normally up to the device says "Fully Charged"?

Comment: You might wish to check with [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1020/16575) / [Am I overcharging my phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22160/16575) / [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/55439/16575)

Answer (score 1):

especially on a rapid-charger, this is normal charging behavior to achieve complete 'depth' of charge. I wish they wouldn't report it as "charged/100%" if it was still trickling.

Here is a graph of the charge curve. note the voltage on the battery tops out but the current is still drawn.

[image: charging]

It's somewhat an EE question, but higher voltage is provided to the battery until the charge rate (current draw) drops to 5-2% of C, with C being the total storage. IE, on a 3000mAh battery this would be a charge rate of 60mA. Lower cutoffs (1%) are detrimental to battery health (IE, over 3-500 charges degrades capacity by, oh, 5-10%), but given OEM replacement batteries are $10-15 FOB from China, it is wiser to consider them sacrificial and not concern yourself with their health.

I know it's a shift in thinking but it's much easier to [convert to Qi charging](http://smile.amazon.com/BLUBOON-Universal-Wireless-Micro-usb-Narrow-interface/dp/B00MN3RR7Q/) (just get a TPU case too to help hold it on) and just drop it on the pad whenever you are at work or at home. Once you have a phone with Qi you won't be interested in one without. plugging in twice a day (once to top up) is hard.