# Can over charging damage battery?

Tags: battery, charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-android-cellphone)

**Indeed, this is a duplicate of:** [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-android-cellphone)

Just for the record -- let's say I leave phone charging for 8 hours, it will charge to 100% in 2 hours, so for the last 6 hours would be over charging.

I used dumb phones (Nokias) this way for years, and nothing bad happened. I did it few times with Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, but after I heard some rumor it could damage the phone I try to disconnect the phone once it reaches 100%. Yesterday after 5 minutes of over charging the battery dropped from 100% to 77% in few hours in pure stand-by mode (no net, no gps, no calls, nothing, just waiting for action).

No wonder I am now afraid of the battery life and also interested in getting **facts**. So far I found only just statements -- in case of iPhone "overcharging means no harm", in case of Android "oh God, no, it will ruin your battery".

So -- can over charging damage battery? I am only interested in **facts** (no "no/yes" answers please, explanation "why" is needed here) and/or also long-standing experience.

*I am interested in this issue, because as developer I will connect phone to computer for longer than 2 hours, and charging is unavoidable.*

Comment: @roxan, good call, I leave the question though, because it is better to avoid duplicates in future, than delete it, and repeat the scenario again ;-) I hope I don't get any negative points for that.

Comment: Don't worry this question will automatically get closed  once it gets enough close votes.