# Preventing charging while USB debugging - One X

Tags: charging, usb-debugging, htc-one-x

I am often using my device to develop, so I'm a little bit worried that the constant charging might fry the battery. Is there anyway to use USB debugging while not charging the phone?

Comment: I know many phones that complain the charger should be unplugged. I wonder why they don't have an electronic switch that takes care of this.

Comment: No need to worry. Constant charging won't harm the modern batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, batteries won't fry on constant charging. They chips in them that control overcharging and low charge. So they won't die easyly. I am using my desire just like you explained for almost 2 years and it is just like the first day, I need to charge it every day :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an hardware issue that is easy to fix: charging is done with the USB cable. My answer is to cut the wire of the USB cable. Or more simply, you can "cut" the courant by placing a tape or any other non conducting material on the appropriate pin.

The spec of USB are easy to find, eg http://www.kineteka.com/microusb-b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about it.  Lithium Ion batteries used in most (all?) modern phones are not as sensitive to "top-off" charging as NiCd batteries, which have "memory" and stop accepting a full charge.   Searching "lithium ion battery" on this site will bring up many discussions, such as [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1023/155).