# should you be on a tablet when its charging?

Tags: charging, tablet

is it OK for the battery if you keep using the tablet while it's charging? And should you stop charging when it's fully charged.

Comment: For the second part of your question, see [Is it better to detach a charger when my Android device gets fully charged?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51407/) and [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/).

Comment: Also see: [Is it safe to use phone while charging with portable powerbank?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58770/16575) / [What happens when using a cellphone when charging?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55293/16575)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a tablet while it is charging. But, if you do something cpu intense (like 3d game) it can become a little hot.

No, you don't need to stop charging when fully charged. The tablet will make sure you don't overcharge.

Answer (score -1):

1. It's advisable not to play graphic intensive games while charging, the cpu and graphics chipset gets hot which is not good for a long run meaning decreases longevity of the device.
2. Please disconnect the device from charge after a full charge i.e 100%, good for longevity of the battery.
3. To further increase the longevity of the battery you can keep charge cycle of 10%-90% or 20%-80% every time charging the device  and give a full charge i.e 100% atleast once per month. 
   P. S -  Number 3 Point only if you want to be extra careful with your battery. What I always do and is normally advisable never let battery go below 10% and never leave it charging once it says fully charged.