# Is there a way to leave the phone plugged in, but schedule when to actually charge it?

Tags: battery, charging

Under my normal daily use, my phone would have around 50~40% battery power left before I go to sleep.  I don't want to keep my phone plugged in to charge over night, but I do want it to be at 100% when I wake up.  Is there a way to disable charging while it is plugged in, and re-enable at a scheduled time?  i.e. one hour prior to I wake up.

Nexus 6 32GB rooted currently running CHROMA, using Motorola Turbo Charger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you want to keep the phone plugged in overnight? Per [Is it better to detach a charger when my Android device gets fully charged?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51408/112477), it sounds like sitting at 100% on the charger for ~6 hours is not considered harmful to the lithium-ion battery in your device.

That said, you can purchase a [light timer](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&tbs=vw:l,mr:1,price:1,ppr_max:20&tbm=shop&q=light+timer) for under $20, set it to only turn on for an hour or two in the morning, and plug your charger into it at night.

But actually, if your phone drains by over 50% during the day, this is probably not the ideal solution, because allowing the battery to drain further overnight until the timer kicks on means that it will discharge even more deeply than it currently does, which will wear down the battery's capacity far more quickly over time than being at 100% charge for 6 hours per day will.
So an optimum cycle might be to charge it to 100% in the afternoon, when it's only down to, say, 70% charge, instead of waiting for bedtime; and *then* put it on the timer as described above when you go to bed. Just be sure to give it a full discharge occasionally (once every 2-4 weeks sounds about right based on your usage).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like for simplicity, the phone is better off being plugged in at 100% for 6+ hours, than being 40 -> 20% for 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading some smart charging apps mentioned below:

- [DU Battery Saver丨Power Doctor](http://www.9apps.com/android-apps/dianxinos-dxbs/)
- [CM Battery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.battery)
- [Battery Doctor (Battery Saver)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijinshan.kbatterydoctor_en)

If you want to know what smart charging is, please visit [this website](http://www.batterystuff.com/blog/3-stages-of-smart-chargers.html).

Why should I download these apps?

Well basically the trickle charging is the most important part of these apps, when you wake up your phone would still be going from 99-100%, 99-100% without overheating your phone.

Comment: https://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/59962116/?countrycode=CA&lang=en

Comment: This will work too http://www.9apps.com/android-apps/dianxinos-dxbs/

Comment: If you want to know what smart charging is, please visit this website: http://www.batterystuff.com/blog/3-stages-of-smart-chargers.html

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.battery&hl=en

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijinshan.kbatterydoctor_en&hl=en