# Use android device to host a website

Tags: web-server

I have an [Xperia Mini](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_xperia_mini-3947.php) which I want to make a web server, to host a website on it so me and other people can visit the website (it won't be something like 1000 visitors per minute). So, if this is possible, can you please:

- Point me at what to read about this, so I can set it myself
- Tell me if the phone can run only on a charger, without a battery (because I expect it won't live long if the battery is constantly charging)

Comment: Install the corresponding app, and there you go. Oh: Find it in my list of [Webserver Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_web): Simple web server, such with scripting support, and even ones with the entire stack (including MySQL or other databases). As for the battery question: see our [battery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery/info), and especially [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1020/16575)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Webserver on Android for example :
[KSWEB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb&hl=en)

but, there is 2 Case for use with Android Device :

**First** :

> your phone Broadband is how much ?
>
> this Broadband can support users
>   and online at 24 hours of day ?

**second** :

this is not good idea for `start webhosting` or other something with a Android device.your hardware need backup and set other Options...

and about Questions :

***1.***

> Point me at what to read about this, so I can set it myself

yes you can.use below link :

```
http://www.androidguys.com/2014/04/22/host-website-android-device/
```

***2.***

> Tell me if the phone can run only on a charger, without a battery
>   (because I expect it won't live long if the battery is constantly
>   charging)

i have no idea, But this links maybe can help you :

```
http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/can-i-directly-power-an-android-device-by-circumventing-its-battery/

www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp_sJYQR1Bg
```