# Can there be problems if I leave my old android phone alwys plugged to electricity?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

I have an old Android phone. I want to use it as small router and media center.

I don't want to be pluging it all the time to charge, plus the battery is close to dead.

Is it ok  to leave it always plugged to electricity?

I am not worried with the battery life or even the device. I am mostly afraid of overheat, short circuit, or anything else that may create a risk other than the phone (fire, electrical circuit break, etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-android-cellphone)

Comment: @dr01 - I'd argue against that, since they're not concerned with the battery life of the device when it's off the charger in their usecase (which is what 99% of the linked question is answering).

Answer (score 1):

Almost all concerns with phones remaining plugged in indefinitely stem from the health of the battery. Mentioning that the device is old and has a worn battery (and odn't want to deal with charging it constantly) means we can ignore those potential challenges. Refer to the question that user "dr01" [linked](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-android-cellphone) if you want more info on that.

As for damaging/overheating your phone - that depends on your device and what your usecase for it is. Using it as a mini media centre and router will make sure it's at least warm all the time - but shouldn't cause any damage to it if the device doesn't have a history of being hot under normal use.